# JList fills whole window upon adding elements

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jlist, gridbaglayout

I have a `JList` in a `GridBagLayout`. After launching the window it looks just fine, but when I add elements to the `JList` it immediately fills the whole window and overlaps the other components.

```
    paragraphlst = new JList<ParagraphItem>();
    paragraphlst.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
    paragraphlst.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    paragraphlst.setAutoscrolls(true);

    paragraphlstmodel = new DefaultListModel<ParagraphItem>();
    paragraphlst.setModel(paragraphlstmodel);
```

Adding an element:

```
view.getParagraphLstModel().addElement(
                        new ParagraphItem(rt.getNumString() + " "
                                + paragraphString, wordMLPackage
                                .getMainDocumentPart().getContent()
                                .indexOf(jaxbNode)));
```

Window after adding elements:

[image]

How It should look:

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Did you put the `JList` in a `JScrollPane`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, the problem was I didnt check the length of the string I add to the list.
With the following Code it works.

```
            temp = temp.length() > 15 ? temp.substring(0, 15) : temp;
            temp =  rt.getNumString()+" "+temp;

            view.getParagraphLstModel().addElement(
                    new ParagraphItem(temp, wordMLPackage
                            .getMainDocumentPart().getContent()
                            .indexOf(jaxbNode)));
```